# Capture Approval Date

Tags: trigger, approval-process

Please help.
All my account needs to undergo approval process.
I need to create a field in Account to Capture the approval date under Approval history section.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I understand your question correctly but in the Approval Process wizard, under **Final Approver Actions** you can choose **Add New > Field Update**, select the Date field you want to update and use a formula which should probably just be

```
Today();
```

I can't see why that wouldn't work.

You could also set the field level security of the Date field so that it is read-only too which I believe won't affect the Approval Process writing to the field, just prevent users from modifying it.

**Edit:**
I can see you've tagged this question with Trigger although you don't mention this in your actual question itself. However, based on what you've said, I don't think it's necessary to write a Trigger for this. It could just been done in the approval process itself.